# (PHP) How do I properly concatenate a list of arrays into a string for file_put_contents?

Tags: php, arrays, string, concatenation, file-put-contents

I've been playing around with a php input function that will build a html page for a game, something like a wiki. All is going fine and dandy but when trying to build an array into a string it's passing back some funny errors.

It's happening to every one that involves an array and I've snipped some code out that works independently to save me time, but just can't figure it out. I'm using the Linux Terminal to run the script and when I set it to echo inside the foreach loop it does it just fine, it just won't when I try building it into a HTML file.

Here is the input script:

```
echo "\nHow many ranks were there (number)?:\n";
$facInputRankLimit = readline();
echo "Please read carefully and supply the ranks in descending order (HIGHEST > LOWEST):\n";
$facInputRankCount = 0;
$facInputRankString = "";
while ($facInputRankCount < $facInputRankLimit) {
    echo "Enter a rank:\n";
    $facInputRanks[$facInputRankCount] = readline();
    $facInputRankCount++;
}
foreach ($facInputRanks as $facInputRankList) {
    $facInputRankString .= $facInputRankList.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Then I'll build it into a multi-line echo (rather than appending every single block of code):

```
$facBuildPage = <<<EOT
<?php
\$facRankLimit = '$facInputRankLimit';
\$facRanks = '$facInputRankString';

include('faction2.html');
?>
EOT;
```

The variables with the backslashes will then be built into "$facFileName.php" and will be a set of variables inputted through this script (input2.php), which will each also include the same html page.

To top it off I'm getting really weird results... if I create 5 ranks, each as "1 2 3 4 5", I actually get "1  2  3" with two vertical linebreaks in between.

Edit: Snipped some of it, I didn't want to risk not adding enough info but it turns out I added a bit much.

For instance, the input I'm giving is:

```
$facInputRankLimit = 5;
$facInputRanks[1] = 1; -> $facInputRanks[5] = 5;
```

But it prints:

```
1<br><br>2<br><br>3
```

@Deepkak - The relative code in faction2.html is:

```
<div class="fpDivisions fpBox">
    <span class="header">Ranks</span><br>
    <?php
        $facRankCount = 0;
        while ($facRankCount < $facRankLimit) {
            echo $facRanks[$facRankCount].'<br>';
            $facRankCount++;
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share expected input and your current output

Comment: Oh my that's a lot of text for such a simple question. Can you scale down the question to "what is relevant"?

Comment: [edit] your question.

Comment: Did you look at [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: What is there in faction2.html

Comment: I've also tried implode() but now it's only showing the first word with each letter split with a linebreak. I think I know the issue I just don't know how to fix it. It's either grabbing or saving each $facInputRanks[$facInputRankCount] as a single character when it should be saving/grabbing it as a string. I've tried encasing $facInputRankCount in single and double quotes but then it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will solve the issue

```
<?php
echo "\nHow many ranks were there (number)?:\n";
$facInputRankLimit = readline();
echo "Please read carefully and supply the ranks in descending order (HIGHEST > LOWEST):\n";
$facInputRankCount = 0;
while ($facInputRankCount < $facInputRankLimit) {
    echo "Enter a rank:\n";
    $facInputRanks[$facInputRankCount] = readline();
    $facInputRankCount++;
}
$array = [];
foreach ($facInputRanks as $facInputRankList) {
    $array[] = "'".$facInputRankList."'";
}
$facInputRankString = "[".implode(",",$array)."]";

$facBuildPage = <<<EOT
<?php
\$facRankLimit = '$facInputRankLimit';
\$facRanks = $facInputRankString;

include('faction2.html');
?>
EOT;

echo $facBuildPage;
```

Comment: I've removed .PHP_EOL and it works fine but now it's gone back to the original issue of only using the first letter of each array item. If I use the following 5: "rank1, rank2, rank3, rank4, rank5" they each only print the letter R.

Comment: Now that's just printing "[<br>]"

Comment: use foreach instead of for loop in faction2.html

Answer (score 0):

I've created a workaround for this, incase anyone needs any help in the future. It was as simple as echoing it from the HTML page, rather than creating a loop that runs through both the PHP script and the HTML code.

PHP input code:

```
echo "\nHow many ranks were there (number)?:\n";  
$facInputRankLimit = readline();  
echo "Please read carefully and supply the ranks in descending order (HIGHEST > LOWEST):\n";  
$facInputRankCount = 0;  
while ($facInputRankCount < $facInputRankLimit) {  
    echo "Enter a rank:\n";  
    $facInputRanks[$facInputRankCount] = readline();  
    $facInputRankCount++;
}
$facInputList = implode("<br>", $facInputRanks);
```

PHP output code:

```
$facBuildPage = <<<EOT
<?php
    \$facRanks = '$facInputList';

    include('faction2.html');
?>
EOT;

file_put_contents("test/$facFileName.php", $facBuildPage);
```

HTML output code:

```
<div class="fpDivisions fpBox">
    <span class="header">Ranks</span><br>
    <?php echo $facRanks; ?>
</div>
```